# Prove that these conditions for linear operators are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ be a linear operators $V \rightarrow W$. Prove that these conditions are equivalent:

1. $\ker \mathcal{A} \subset \ker \mathcal{B}$
2. There is exists linear operator $\mathcal{C}: W \rightarrow W$ such that $\mathcal{B=CA}$.

It seems to me that $(2 \Rightarrow 1)$ is not very hard to show. Let $w \in \ker \mathcal{A}$ and $w \notin \ker \mathcal{B}$. Then $\mathcal{B}w = \mathcal{CA}w = 0$, therefore $w \in \mathcal{\ker B}$. But I'm stuck with proving $(1 \Rightarrow 2)$. I tried to write $W$ as a direct sum of $\ker \mathcal{A}$, $\ker \mathcal{B} \backslash \ker {\mathcal{A}}$ and $im \mathcal{B}$, but can't understand what am I supposed to do. How exactly can I show that $\mathcal{C}$ exists? Should I express exact formula for this operator? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If you want people here to help you please try to demonstrate your attempts towards solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It suffices to define $C$ properly on the image of $A$, then you can extend to a map on all of $W$. There you would like to define $C(w) = B(A^{-1}(w))$, and you need to check that $C$ is well-defined (independent of a choice of preimage $A^{-1}(w)$) and linear.

Or, perhaps in more precise terms, the fact that $\ker(A) \subset \ker(B)$ and the fundamental homomomorphism theorem tells you that there is a unique homomorphism (linear map)$$\operatorname{im}(A) \cong V/\ker(A) \to W$$ through which $B$ factors.